# Search only four words from a Recognized text using C program

Tags: c, string, if-statement, logical-operators

I used pocketsphinx speech recognition program for speech to text application. I created my own acoustic model in German for some 50 commands. A part of it is to recognize a persons ID. When i say Fahrerkennung, It should wait till you say your four digit ID. Initially i did it with Numbers 1,2,3. After any four numbers are recognized ..It will give output

I have changed my Acoustic model from 1,2,3... to EINS, ZWEI, DREI....(German numbers). That means Instead of direkt 1,2,3 ... we have the word representation of numbers like ONE, TWO, THREE--- we have EINS, ZWEI , DREI in German..

I am confused How to get this similar to what i did here using digits(see below) !! Now they are nomore numbers at the output of hyp, so we will get "EINS DREI VIER FüNF"

I want to only print output if any of the four combinations from the set of Numbers "EINS ZWEI DREI VIER FüNF SECHS SIEBEN ACHT NEUN NULL" is occured and rest(if i say someother command apart from four numbers) should be ignored.It should be done using C programming

Initially the recognized texts are stored in a vriable 'hyp'

```
    else if (strcmp(word, "FAHRERKENNUNG") == 0 &&(token==500)) 
    {
        //counter_correct = counter_correct + 1;
        token = 496;
        printf("Fahrerkennung on process                            \n");
        //printf("token number %d\n", token);
        printf("Enter the four digit of your drivers id             \n");

    }
    else if(isdigit(hyp[0])
         && isdigit(hyp[2])
         && isdigit(hyp[4])
         && isdigit(hyp[6])
         && (token==496))
    {
        counter_correct = counter_correct + 1;
        sscanf(hyp,"%d %d %d %d",&Nummer1,&Nummer2,&Nummer3,&Nummer4);
        if(Nummer1==0)
        {
            id = Nummer1*1000+Nummer2*100+Nummer3*10+Nummer4;
            printf("The drivers id detected %.4d \n",id);
            //printf("%s: %s\n", uttid, hyp);
            printf("score %d/%s \n",counter_correct,uttid);
            token=500;
        }        
        else  
        {
            id = Nummer1*1000+Nummer2*100+Nummer3*10+Nummer4;
            counter_correct = counter_correct + 1;
            printf("The drivers id detected %d \n",id);
            //printf("%s: %s\n", uttid, hyp);
            printf("score %d/%s \n",counter_correct,uttid);
            token=500;        
        }        
    }
```

I also thought of doing like this

```
        else if (strcmp(word, "FAHRERKENNUNG") == 0 &&(token==500)) 
        {
            //counter_correct = counter_correct + 1;
            token = 496;

            printf("Fahrerkennung on process                            \n");
            //printf("token number %d\n", token);
            printf("Enter the four digit of your drivers id             \n");    
        }
        else if((strstr(hyp,"NULL") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"EINS") == 0)  
            || (strstr(hyp,"ZWEI") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"DREI") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"VIER") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"FüNF") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"SECHS") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"SIEBEN") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"ACHT") == 0) 
            || (strstr(hyp,"NEUN") == 0)
            && (token==496))
        {    
            printf("%s\n",hyp);   
            token=500;       
        }
```

The problem here is after fahrerkennung if i say something which is another command, it is also giving it as a output. I want to only continue the process till we get any four combinations of numbers at output.

Thank you very much.. If you need more clarification ..feel free to ask. Cheers !

Comment: Can you please edit your first paragraph? It's a bit unreadable at the moment, and not entirely clear to me. Try separating it into paragraphs, for example.

Comment: yeah. also consider some indentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to put the parsing in a function:

```
// Store the strings to look for
const char * digits [] = {"NULL", "EINS", "ZWEI", "DREI", "VIER", "FüNF", "SECHS", "ACHT",  "NEUN"}; 

size_t count_numbers_in_str(char * str)
{
     size_t digits_found = 0;
     for(size_t i=0; i<10; i++) // i<10: there are 10 elements in digits[]
     {
         char * tmp = str;
         while(1)
         {
             tmp = strstr(tmp, digits[i]);
             if(tmp) // Found a match
             {
                 digits_found++;
                 // tmp points to the beginning of the found string
                 // move it 1 step forward to look for a new occurence
                 tmp++;
             }
             else // No matches or end of the string
             {
                 break; // Exit while loop
             }
         }
    }
    // End of for loop: we looked for all digits in our list
    return digits_found;
}
```

Then call this function every time you want to look for digits. Continue your process only if the function returns `4` i.e. a combination of four digits have been found in the given string.

**[EDIT]** Note that this count all the occurrences of a string representation of digit in a given `str`. For example, if "SECHS" appears twice, `digits_found` will be incremented twice.
This process is done for all strings in `digits`.
Therefore, it can recognize any random combination of these substrings in `str`.

Comment: Hi.. Could you look for the following case. "Not all numbers are having four characters " For example 6 (SECHS) and 7 (SIEBEN) have more than four letters.

So how to control the matching.. and The combination of 4 Numbers can be very random

Comment: This case is handled in the code above: the declaration of `digits` allows any length for the strings: I put `"..."` because I was too lazy too type all the german numbers ^^
This function shall recognize any combination of numbers, provided you put them in `digits` list

Comment: Yes. It helped a lot. hence, I marked it as answer. Thank you